# R Creating new columns based on factors in another column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I'm new in R; trying to do some basic data manipulations. However, I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days.

Suppose I have a data frame like the below and it contains 60 obs which every variable in the "category" column has the same amount:

```
  category cond 
1      A  1
2      B  2
3      C  1
4      D  1
5      E  1
6      F  3
7      A  5
8      B  0
..     .. ..
60     F  2
```

Desired new data frame (by the "cond" column):

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F
1   1  2  1  1  0  3
2   5  0  .  .  .  .
3   .  .  .  .  .  .
.   .  .  .  .  .  .
.   .  .  .  .  .  .
10  .  .  .  .  .  2
```

Since the first data frame has a 60 row(all variables in the "category" column has equal number 60/6=10) new data frame has 10 rows.

I've tried this for example

```
A<-old%>% filter(category =="A")%>%summarise(`cond`)
B<-old%>% filter(category =="B")%>%summarise(`cond`)
new<-cbind(A,B)
```

...
..
This works for me but it's taking a lot of time and changing column names another part of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried transposing with `t()`? Such that `t(data)`.

Comment: Yes, I tried this function but it did not give me the correct results that I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
df %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% ungroup() %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = category, values_from = cond) %>% select(-id)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I had never encountered some of the functions that you've written while learning Tidyverse. Now I will make some more practice with them. Thank you so much!

Comment: Read [this](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/) from the author of tidyverse

Answer (score 0):

Is there a typo in your expected result?

At a untested guess:

```
require(dplyr)
old %>%
spread(A,B) -> new
```

Comment: Thank you for your attention, but my question has been solved by AnilGoyal.You can also check his solution.

Comment: This won't do, by the way